# Blackberry Work Profile issue with camera and file download using Webworks/Cordova,

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

Do we need any special permission for an app to work in Work Profile, we have developed a webworks application(using Cordova/PhoneGap), and when we tested it in Personal Profile, it is working fine in all the devices (Q10,Z10 and Q5).
But the same application does not work in Work Profile.

We have given all the these permissions in config file.

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="file:///accounts/"></access>
<access subdomains="true" uri="file:///accounts/100/shared/camera/"></access>
<rim:permissions>
<rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
<rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>
```

Here are the issue we are facing in work profile:
1)Application is not able to download pdf file.
2)Camera is not getting launched.

Do we have to configure some thing special in Work profile, as we don't face the above issue in Personal Profile.